# Finding a holomorphic 1-form in one chart that extends to a nearby coordinate domain.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry, differential-forms

I know that for a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$, there should be $g$ different globally defined holomorphic 1-forms. However, I am having trouble finding any in my case.
Here is the set up:

Let $M$ be a compact Riemann surface. Suppose that there are coordinate domains $U_z$ and $U_w$ both identified with the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$ such that on $U_z\cap U_w$, $z=-\frac{1}{w}$. Then, does there exist a holomorphic 1-form defined on $U_z$ which extends to a 1-form on $U_w$?

More generally, are there any good resources for learning more about this type of construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that $z=-1/w$, you should be able to deduce that no holomorphic $1$-form on $U_z$ can be extended to $U_w$. Indeed, suppose $\eta=f(z)dz$ for some holomorphic function $f:U_z\to\mathbb{C}$. Write $f(z)=\sum c_kz^k$. Then the change of coordinates $z\mapsto -1/w$ takes $\eta\mapsto f(-1/w)d(-1/w)=\frac{-1}{w^2}\sum c_k\frac{1}{w^k}$ which is not holomorphic at $0$ (unless $\eta=0$). This should not be surprising news to you. The coordinate transformation $z\mapsto 1/w$ is the one which corresponds to $\mathbb{CP}^1$ and its standard open cover, which consists of the two hemispheres. Since $g(\mathbb{CP}^1)=0$, you know that there indeed aren't any non-trivial holomorphic $1$-forms on $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

Fermat curves give us examples where it's possible to explicitly compute a basis for $\Gamma(X,\Omega^1_X)$. The notation below will be slightly different from what you are using, because I've copy pasted this from some notes I wrote a while ago. The notation $Z(f)$ denotes the vanishing locus of the function $f$.

Consider the Fermat curve $X=Z(U^n+V^n-W^n)\subset\mathbb{CP}^2$. On the affine patch $D(W)$ (i.e. where $W\neq 0$), take coordinates $u=U/W$ and $v=V/W$. Define a $1$-form on the open subset $D(u)$ where $u\neq 0$ by $\frac{dv}{nu^{n-1}}$. The affine curve $D(W)$ is defined as $Z(u^n+v^n-1)$, so $d(u^n)+d(v^n)=0$, meaning $nu^{n-1}du=-nv^{n-1}dv$. On the intersection $D(u)\cap D(v)$, we then get
$$\frac{dv}{nu^{n-1}}=\frac{-du}{nv^{n-1}}$$
Clearly, the latter extends to $D(v)$ holomorphically. Since $D(W)=D(u)\cup D(v)$, this means we can glue the two to get a holomorphic $1$-form on $D(W)$. We want to extend this to $D(W)\cup D(U)=X$. Choose coordinates $x=V/U$ and $y=W/U$ on $D(U)$. Then $D(U)=Z(1+x^n-y^n)$. On the intersection $D(U)\cap D(W)$, we have $v=x/y$ and $u=1/y$. This leads to
\begin{align*}
    dv=d(x/y)=\frac{dx}{y}-\frac{xdy}{y^2}\implies \frac{dv}{nu^{n-1}}=\frac{y^{n-2}dx}{n}-\frac{xy^{n-3}dy}{n}
\end{align*}
Assuming that $n\geq 3$, this can evidently be extended holomorphically to all of $D(U)$. Thus, we can glue the $1$-forms on $D(U)$ and $D(W)$ to get a non-constant $1$-form $\eta\in\Omega^1_X(X)$.

In fact, we can produce more $1$-forms on the Fermat curve by a similar argument. Consider the $1$-form
$$\frac{v^kdv}{nu^m}\in\Omega^1_X(D(u))$$
Using that $dv=\frac{u^{n-1}du}{v^{n-1}}$ again, we see that on the intersection $D(u)\cap D(v)$, we may write $$\frac{v^kdv}{nu^m}=\frac{v^{k-n+1}du}{u^{m-n+1}}\in\Omega^1_X(D(u)\cap D(v))$$
This expression can be holomorphically extended to $D(v)$ if and only if $0\leq m\leq n-1$. Suppose this holds, and we want to extend to all of $X$. The same relations between $x,y,u,v$ on $D(U)\cap D(W)$ as before yield
\begin{align*}
    \frac{v^kdv}{nu^m}=\frac{(x/y)^k}{n(1/y)^m}(\frac{dx}{y}-\frac{xdy}{y^2})=\frac{x^ky^{m-k}}{n}(\frac{dx}{y}-\frac{xdy}{y^2})=\frac{x^ky^{m-k-1}}{n}dx-\frac{x^{k+1}y^{m-k-2}}{n}dy
\end{align*}
Once again, these may be extended to all of $D(W)$ if and only if $0\leq k\leq m-2$. Thus, we get $(n-1)(n-2)/2=g(X)$ choices of $m$ and $k$ that yield a holomorphic $1$-form on $X$. Using Riemann-Roch, one can in fact show that $\Gamma(X,\Omega^1_X)$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space of dimension $g(X)$, which means that we have produced a basis for $\Gamma(X,\Omega^1_X)$ (at least, after you show that they are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$).

The above example illustrates that the precise form in which your Riemann surface appears is quite important. It's not just a topological surface, it also has a complex structure, and you need to specify this complex structure before you can perform the calculation that you are asking about. For more information, I would refer to Rick Miranda's book "Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces".

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response! The first paragraph was a great sanity check. What is this saying about surfaces with this type of patching more generally? If I have coordinates patched together in this reciprocal fashion does that mean there are no globally defined nontrivial holomorphic 1-forms at all? Even if the genus is not zero? Does this mean I made a mistake when defining my coordinate system? 

The later paragraphs are a great example I will reference Miranda and try to understand what is going on more fully. 

Thanks again

Comment: That depends on whether you include the origin of the disk in your coordinate chart. If you have only two charts, and the transition function is the one you wrote, then you'll get the projective line. If you exclude the origin from one of the charts, you'll get a non-compact surface and you'll have to glue something else onto it, and maybe obtain something else. But what you described are two coordinate charts which yield a closed Riemann surface, namely the projective line.